# Hierarchical Query, Subquery Linq to Entities

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am not so familiar with LINQ and entity framwework yet.

I have to get a sitemap from a database and write it to an XML.

The main problem is, that in the following code the subquery is not showing anything at all:

```
var pages = (from p in ctx.CMSPages2
                 where p.MenuID == num && p.ParentID == 0
                 select new
                 {
                     URLLevel1 = p.KeywordUrl + "/" + p.FriendlyUrl,
                     TitleLevel1 = p.LinkTitle,
                     Level2 = from q in ctx.CMSPages2
                              where q.ParentID == p.SitemapExternID
                              select new
                              {
                                  URLLevel2 = q.KeywordUrl + "/" + q.FriendlyUrl,
                                  TitleLevel2 = q.LinkTitle,
                              }


                 }).ToArray();
```

Any Ideas?

Update:

Using the navigation property (CMSPages2_1) did the trick:

```
 var pages = (from p in ctx.CMSPages2
                 where p.MenuID == num && p.ParentID == 0
                 select new
                 {
                     URLLevel1 = p.KeywordUrl + "/" + p.FriendlyUrl,
                     TitleLevel1 = p.LinkTitle,
                     Level2 = (from o in p.CMSPages2_1
                               where o.ParentID == p.SitemapExternID
                               select new
                               {
                                   URLLevel2 = o.KeywordUrl + "/" + o.FriendlyUrl,
                                   TitleLevel2 = o.LinkTitle,
                               })






                 }).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you execute only the sub query, it returns anything?

Comment: Could you post the table layout?

Comment: The sub query alone works, if I add 
    from p in ctx.CMSPages2 
after 
    from q in ctx.CMSPages2

Comment: Which kind of table format do you want to see? The table has a lot of fields...

Comment: What I really like to achieve is something like this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx

Only with a sitemap and a self referencing table...

Comment: What database are you using? If its MS SQL, then would it be easier to use rCTEs to just build the result set, without using LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery for Level2 would be returning a collection, whereas it looks like you're trying to populate a single-object property.

Try using FirstOrDefault:

```
var pages = (from p in ctx.CMSPages2
         where p.MenuID == num && p.ParentID == 0
         select new
         {
            URLLevel1 = p.KeywordUrl + "/" + p.FriendlyUrl,
            TitleLevel1 = p.LinkTitle,
            Level2 = ctx.CMSPages2
                .FirstOrDefault(q => q.ParentID == p.SitemapExternID) 
                .Select(x => new
                    {
                        URLLevel2 = x.KeywordUrl + "/" + x.FriendlyUrl,
                        TitleLevel2 = x.LinkTitle,
                    });


        }).ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**:
I didn't notice this was a tree.

Perhaps try setting a navigation property on CMSPages2 to istelf (say "SubPages"), then 
 do something like

```
var pages = (from p in ctx.CMSPages2
         where p.MenuID == num && p.ParentID == 0
         select new
         {
            URLLevel1 = p.KeywordUrl + "/" + p.FriendlyUrl,
            TitleLevel1 = p.LinkTitle,
            Level2 = p.SubPages
                .Select(q => new
                    {
                        URLLevel2 = q.KeywordUrl + "/" + q.FriendlyUrl,
                        TitleLevel2 = q.LinkTitle,
                    });


        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Good Point. But I would like to get a collection there. I tried a .ToList() at the end, but then it says something like this is not supported by the entity framework

Comment: I also tried your modification with some minor changes. But the problem persisted. The problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: I tried again and with another modification now I was able to see something with adding a FirstOrDefault(). If "Level2" is not able to work with a list, why does that work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx ?